# Is it possible to make a required property, optional in an intersection type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently extending the [Material UI date picker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DateTimePicker) and was wondering how to make the required props optional (as default values are provided by the parent component).

My current code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  DatePicker,
  DatePickerProps as MuiDatePickerProps,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

type MyDatePickerProps = {
  value?: string | Date;
  onChange?: (
    date: MaterialUiPickersDate,
    value?: string | null | undefined
  ) => void;
};

function MuiDatePicker(props: MuiDatePickerProps): JSX.Element {
  <DatePicker
    value={props.value}
    onChange={props.onChange}
    clearable={props.clearable}
    format={props.format}
    disableFuture={props.disableFuture}
    disablePast={props.disablePast}
    allowKeyboardControl={props.allowKeyboardControl}
    openTo={props.openTo}
    views={props.views}
    className={props.className}
  />;
}

export default function MyDatePicker({
  allowKeyboardControl = true,
  clearable = false,
  disableFuture = false,
  disablePast = false,
  format = "dd.MM.yyyy",
  keyboardInputDatePicker = false,
  label = "keyboard",
  locale = LOCALE_DEFAULT,
  value = new Date(),
  ...rest
}: MuiDatePickerProps & MyDatePickerProps) {
  const handleDateChange = (date: MaterialUiPickersDate) => {
    setDateValue(date);
  };
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} locale={LOCALE_MAP[locale]}>
      <DatePicker
        allowKeyboardControl={allowKeyboardControl}
        className={className}
        clearable={clearable}
        disableFuture={disableFuture}
        disablePast={disablePast}
        format={format}
        openTo={openTo}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        value={dateValue}
        views={views}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

When I try to use my component (without setting the `onChange` and `value`, I get an error saying `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'BasePickerProps': value, onChange`

Comment: could you please provide minimum reproducable example ?

Comment: Are you really just looking for something like [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the suggestion, can't believe I overlooked it!

Comment: You can also use Omit<BasePickerProps, keyof MyDatePickerProps> to remove the props which are being handled elsewhere.  You would need this instead of just Partial<BasePickerProps> in the case that you are including a prop with the same key but a different value type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've solved this, but here's a generalized solution to your question.  I come across the case where I want to make certain properties optional enough that I've created an alias for it:

```
export type PartialSome<T, U extends keyof T> = Partial<T> & Omit<T, U>
```

This mapped type alters a type or interface T such that any keys assignable to U become optional, while all other keys stay the same (they can be optional or required).

`Partial<T>` makes everything optional, while joining with `Omit<T, U>` brings everything except for the optional keys back to its original type.